# Using MUI-X DatePicker for a product form submission

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui, react-datepicker, formik-material-ui

I am trying to post product data using axios. When I submit my datas entered in the form, I see this error in the console :
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

This is my React Component code for adding new product, I made a validation for datas using Formik and Yup, my form contains TextFields and Material UI DatePicker, I cast The Date Format to dayjs().

```
import {React} from 'react';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuthContext } from '../../../hooks/useAuthContext';
import axios from 'axios';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

/**************|| Validation : Formik & Yup  ||**************/
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

/**************|| Material UI  ||**************/
import {Grid, Paper, Typography, TextField, Button} from '@mui/material';
import {DemoContainer} from '@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/demo';
import {LocalizationProvider} from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import {AdapterDayjs} from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';

/**************|| React-icons  ||**************/
import { FaGift , FaCartPlus} from "react-icons/fa";
import {MdDescription, MdAddLocation} from "react-icons/md";
import {RiBarcodeBoxLine} from "react-icons/ri";

/************************************************************************************************************/
// Validation Schema for add product fields
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    productName: Yup.string()
                    .required("Le nom du produit est requis.")
                    .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ ]+$/, "Le nom du produit doit être alphanumérique."),
    description: Yup.string()
                    .required("La description est requise.")
                    .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ ]+$/, "La description doit être alphanumérique."),
    manufacturingDate: Yup.date().nullable() 
                        .typeError("La date de fabrication est requise.")
                        .required("La date de fabrication est requise."),
    expiryDate: Yup.date().nullable()
                    .typeError("La date d'expiration est requise.")
                    .when("manufacturingDate",
                         (manufacturingDate, Yup) => manufacturingDate && Yup.min(manufacturingDate, "La date d'expiration doit être après la date de fabrication."))
                    .required("La date d'expiration est requise."),  
    batchNumber: Yup.string()
                    .required("Le numéro de lot est requis.")
                    .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ ]+$/, "Le numéro de lot doit être alphanumérique."),
    quantity: Yup.number()
                .required("La quantité est requise.")
                .positive("La quantité doit être supérieure à zéro.")
                .integer("La quantité doit être un nombre entier."),
    location: Yup.string()
                .required("L'emplacement est requis.")
                .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ ]+$/, "L'emplacement doit être alphanumérique."),
});

const NewProduct = () => {
  // styles
  const paperStyle = { padding: '30px 20px', margin: "20px auto" }
  const headerStyle = { margin: 0, fontWeight:"800" }
  const marginTop = { marginTop: 15 }
/************************************************************************************************************/
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { user } = useAuthContext();

// initial values for form fields
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
        productName: "",
        description: "",
        manufacturingDate: dayjs(),
        expiryDate: dayjs(),
        batchNumber: "",
        quantity: 0,
        location: "",
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      console.log(values);

      // Caster les dates au format Day.js
      values.manufacturingDate = dayjs(values.manufacturingDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      values.expiryDate = dayjs(values.expiryDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

      // Vérifier les données
      if (!values.productName || !values.description || !values.manufacturingDate || !values.expiryDate || !values.batchNumber || !values.quantity || !values.location) {
        throw new Error("Les données sont incomplètes.");
      }

      try {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/products/add",values, {
          headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` }
        });
        console.log(response.status, response.data);
        // Rediriger l'utilisateur vers la page de liste des produits
        navigate('http://localhost:3000/products/list-products');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
      // window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/products/list-products'; 
    },
  });
/************************************************************************************************************ */
  return (
    <>
      <Grid >
        <Paper elevation={20} style={paperStyle}>
          <Grid container direction="column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
            <h2 style={headerStyle}>Ajouter un produit</h2>
            <Typography variant='caption' gutterBottom>Veuillez remplir les détails ci-dessous</Typography>
          </Grid>

          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}> 
            <Grid container spacing={2} columns={16} > 

              {/* Left column */}
              <Grid item xs={8}>
                {/* nom du produit */}
                <TextField 
                  style={marginTop} 
                  id='productName' 
                  fullWidth 
                  label='Nom du produit' 
                  placeholder='Saisir le nom du produit'
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <FaGift />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                  value={formik.values.productName}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  error={formik.touched.productName && Boolean(formik.errors.productName)}
                  helperText={formik.touched.productName && formik.errors.productName}
                />
                {/* description du produit */}
                <TextField 
                  style={marginTop} 
                  id='description' 
                  fullWidth 
                  label='Decription' 
                  placeholder='Saisir la description'
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <MdDescription />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                  value={formik.values.description}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  error={formik.touched.description && Boolean(formik.errors.description)}
                  helperText={formik.touched.description && formik.errors.description}
                />

                {/* date de fabrication + date d'expiration */}
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DemoContainer components={['DatePicker', 'DatePicker']} >
                    {/* date de fabrication */}
                    <DatePicker 
                      required
                      style={marginTop}
                      label="Date de fabrication"
                      value={dayjs(formik.values.manufacturingDate)}
                      onChange={(value) => {formik.setFieldValue('manufacturingDate', dayjs(value));}}  
                      slotProps={{
                        textField: {
                          variant: 'outlined',
                          error: formik.touched.manufacturingDate && Boolean(formik.errors.manufacturingDate),
                          helperText: formik.touched.manufacturingDate && formik.errors.manufacturingDate,
                        },
                      }} 
                    />
                    {/* date d'expiration */}
                    <DatePicker 
                      required 
                      disablePast
                      minDate={dayjs()}
                      style={marginTop}
                      label="Date d'expiration"
                      value={dayjs(formik.values.expiryDate)}
                      onChange={(value) => {formik.setFieldValue('expiryDate', dayjs(value));}}
                      slotProps={{
                        textField: {
                          variant: 'outlined',
                          error: formik.touched.expiryDate && Boolean(formik.errors.expiryDate),
                          helperText: formik.touched.expiryDate && formik.errors.expiryDate,
                        },
                      }} 
                    />
                  </DemoContainer>
                </LocalizationProvider>

              </Grid>

              {/* Right column */}
              <Grid item xs={8}>
                {/* Numéro de lot  */}
                <TextField 
                  style={marginTop} 
                  id='batchNumber' 
                  fullWidth 
                  label='Numéro de lot' 
                  placeholder='Saisir le numéro de lot'
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <RiBarcodeBoxLine />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                  value={formik.values.batchNumber}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  error={formik.touched.batchNumber && Boolean(formik.errors.batchNumber)}
                  helperText={formik.touched.batchNumber && formik.errors.batchNumber}
                />
                {/* Quantité  */}
                <TextField 
                  style={marginTop} 
                  id='quantity' 
                  fullWidth 
                  type='number'
                  inputProps={{min:0}}
                  label='Quantité' 
                  placeholder='Saisir la quantité'
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <FaCartPlus />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                  value={formik.values.quantity}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  error={formik.touched.quantity && Boolean(formik.errors.quantity)}
                  helperText={formik.touched.quantity && formik.errors.quantity}
                />
                {/* Emplacement  */}
                <TextField 
                  style={marginTop} 
                  id='location' 
                  fullWidth 
                  label='Emplacement' 
                  placeholder= "Saisir l'emplacement" 
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <MdAddLocation />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                  value={formik.values.location}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  error={formik.touched.location && Boolean(formik.errors.location)}
                  helperText={formik.touched.location && formik.errors.location}
                />
              </Grid>

              {/* Bottom center */}
              <Grid item xs={16}>
                <Grid container justifyContent="center">
                  <Button type='submit' variant='contained' color='primary' style={marginTop}>
                    Ajouter
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid> 

            </Grid>
          </form>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}

export default NewProduct;
```

My server Code Works and here is my createProduct function:

```
const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const {name, description, manufacturingDate, expiryDate, 
           batchNumber, quantity, location} = req.body;

    const requiredFields = ['name', 'description', 'manufacturingDate', 'expiryDate',
                            'batchNumber', 'quantity', 'location'];
    const emptyFields = requiredFields.filter((field) => !req.body[field]);

    if (emptyFields.length > 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Veuillez remplir tous les champs', emptyFields});
    }

    try {
        const product = await Product.create({
            name,
            description,
            manufacturingDate: dayjs(manufacturingDate,'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate(),
            expiryDate: dayjs(expiryDate,'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate(),
            batchNumber,
            quantity,
            location
            });
        res.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: error.message});
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what is wrong. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: To catch errors in the console with axios, use console.log(error.response.data). This makes it easier to analyze the error you are facing, or try to console.log directly on the server to identify if there is any problem with the data format.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response and just I want to know how could I create the same component with Formik and yup validation for updating my product data ? Because when I try to initialize Formik initialValues with the current data fetched it shows an undefined object despite that my fetch function works correctly, thank you again.